# Wordpress plugin to connect to a REST API?

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest, plugins

Let's say I have a RESTful API running on a server somewhere, as well as a separate, but related, Wordpress site.

I want to have some pages on the WP site that show data on WP pages that has been retrieved from the REST server (in JSON format), and allow the user to view and/or edit the data on WP pages.

For example, let's say I have, as a REST starting point, an API that returns a list of books owned by a user.  I want to display the list of books, allow the user to click on a book link and go to a page that displays the details for the book.

Then if the user enters "edit mode", it lets him/her edit the data and POST/PUT it back to the server via the REST API.

Is there any WP plugin that lets me create pages that display and edit information like this?

I would expect that for each type of entity I could enter some metadata to indicate what to expect in the JSON and how to display it for viewing or how to build the form for it (like [iPhorms](http://codecanyon.net/item/iphorm-simple-yet-powerful-ajax-contact-form/148273) does).

Comment: Will, I see you removed the "rest" tag from my question.  How many times do I need to mention REST in the question to warrant including it?  Five times isn't enough? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So WordPress has some built-in support for AJAX queries, both from the admin panel and in the user-facing pages.

I don't fully understand how it all works yet as I am totally new to WordPress coding, but this seems to be what I want:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Thanks to moimikey for mentioning WP's ajax ability.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this URL, it will solve your problem
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, perhaps this would do the trick.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

It has 3 controllers:

Post:
create_post

Core:
info get_recent_posts get_post get_page get_date_posts get_category_posts get_tag_posts get_author_posts get_search_results get_date_index get_category_index get_tag_index get_author_index get_page_index get_nonce

Respond:
submit_comment

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for.  That lets some other application retrieve your WP content using JSON.  I want to use JSON to create WP pages dynamically.

Comment: I'd look then into utilizing admin-ajax.php. WP has ajax ability built in to accomplish that and practically anything else with add_action('wp_ajax_*, 'your_func');

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I want.  This page has some info and links on the topic: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for similar functionality (I want my Wordpress page to render/update data retrieved from Spring REST CRUD repository) and I couldn't find anything.

I ended up writing my own generic shortcode plugin for Spring REST data repositories, which I will be happy to share once it's completed.

You can also write your own shortcode plugin based on the following tutorials / blog posts, it is fairly straight-forward:

- http://pressupinc.com/blog/2013/09/making-first-shortcode-plugin-wordpress/
- [How to parse json response from CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016506/how-to-parse-json-response-from-curl)
- [Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)

Comment: I would recommend either summarizing the high points of those articles (or of your experience writing the plugin) or waiting to post until the plugin is complete and giving a brief intro to it here.