# Call a REST API in PHP

Tags: php, rest, web-services

Our client had given me a REST API to which I need to make a PHP call. But as a matter of fact, the documentation given with the API is very limited, so I don't really know how to call the service.

I've tried to Google it, but the only thing that came up was an already expired Yahoo! tutorial on how to call the service. Not mentioning the headers or anything in-depth information.

Is there any decent information around how to call a REST API or some documentation about it? Because even in W3schools, they only describe the SOAP method. What are different options for making the rest of API in PHP?

Answer (score 541, accepted):

You can access any REST API with PHPs `cURL` Extension. However, the API Documentation (Methods, Parameters etc.) must be provided by your Client!

Example:

```
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see in the documentation, they are provided. Do you happen to have some documentation about it?

Comment: Thanks Christoph, but where do I place the authentication headers?

Comment: @Michiel I updated my example with a basic Authentication. See the Parameters Section for [curl_setopt](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for other Authentication options.

Comment: So, when calling the function I should get the returned value?

Comment: Just one thing that's not clear to me... What do you mean by the `method`?

Comment: @Michiel: The HTTP Request Method (GET, POST, PUT etc.). Depending on the API there are different methods required. i.e. GET for reading, POST for writing.

Comment: @Michiel `$data` is an associative array (data[fieldname] = value) which holds the data sent to the api method.

Comment: @ChristophWinkler I need to call API (URL) and when I see the code of the API, it has `window.location` in it. So when I call API, the page will be redirected to the next page with wrong app folder. how do I proceed?

Comment: @UserProg `window.location` is a JavaScript function so it shouldn't affect cURL.

Comment: @ChristophWinkler my attempt was unsuccessful but I will try again. By the way this is  my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618842/php-api-call-url-api-redirects-to-different-page-but-i-need-to-be-on-same-pa

Comment: @ChristophWinkler I have tried it using cURL and still the my page is redirected automatically.

Comment: The answer from @colan below is way better - it saves you the whole hassle with building your own error handling and wrapper methods.

Comment: For some reason this only worked once I `json_encode($data)`.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud true and I also had to set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to `array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json');`

Comment: Hello, I use this code and it works great on localhost and also in justhost.com but it does not work on namecheap.com... It returns empty result.. I check curl extension and it is enabled. So why it does not work on namecheap ?

Answer (score 243):

If you have a url and your php supports it, you could just call file_get_contents:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/api/call?param1=5');
```

if $response is JSON, use json_decode to turn it into php array:

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

if $response is XML, use simple_xml class:

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: If the REST endpoint returns an HTTP error status (e.g. 401), the `file_get_contents` function fails with a warning and returns null. If the body contains an error message, you cannot retrieve it.

Comment: Its main drawback is that your PHP installation must have fopen wrappers enabled in order to access URLs. If fopen wrappers is not enabled, you will not be able to use file_get_contents for Web services requests.

Comment: fopen wrappers are among the parts of PHP now seen as a vulnerability, so you're likely to see some hosts disable it.

Answer (score 194):

Use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/).  It's a "PHP HTTP client that makes it easy to work with HTTP/1.1 and takes the pain out of consuming web services".  Working with Guzzle is much easier than working with cURL.

Here's an example from the Web site:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();           // 200
echo $res->getHeader('content-type'); // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();                 // {"type":"User"...'
var_export($res->json());             // Outputs the JSON decoded data
```

Comment: Whoever is still using cURL has never taken a close look at this option.

Comment: Seems nice. But what about fetching PNGs? For map tiles. I can only find JSON data mentioned at the web page you linked.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson, a quick google search revealed what seems to be a decent solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881436/how-to-get-and-display-an-image-from-a-guzzle-request

Answer (score 45):

Using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), you can generate codes to call API for most languages, including `PHP`. Here are the steps:

**Step 1**

Use Postman UI to specify your API call specifications, i.e., `URL`, `method`, `headers`, `parameters`, `body` and etc.

[image]

**Step 2**

On the most right side, there is a small button with which you can see the generated code.

[image]

**Step 3**

Choose your preferred language (and library) from the dropdown and off you go!

[image]

Answer (score 31):

CURL is the simplest way to go. Here is a simple call

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "THE URL TO THE SERVICE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POST DATA);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [HTTPFUL](http://phphttpclient.com/)

Httpful is a simple, chainable, readable PHP library intended to make speaking HTTP sane. It lets the developer focus on interacting with APIs instead of sifting through curl set_opt pages and is an ideal PHP REST client.

Httpful includes...

- Readable HTTP Method Support (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, and OPTIONS)
- Custom Headers
- Automatic "Smart" Parsing
- Automatic Payload Serialization
- Basic Auth
- Client Side Certificate Auth
- Request "Templates"

Ex.

**Send off a GET request. Get automatically parsed JSON response.**

The library notices the JSON Content-Type in the response and automatically parses the response into a native PHP object.

```
$uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%7B%22type%22:%22/music/artist%22%2C%22name%22:%22The%20Dead%20Weather%22%2C%22album%22:%5B%5D%7D";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)->send();

echo 'The Dead Weather has ' . count($response->body->result->album) . " albums.\n";
```

Comment: I am trying to use HTTPFUL as a solution and I am not sure if it can parse the json like `$condition = $response->weather[0]->main;` unless I am just doing the PHP side wrong

Answer (score 13):

You will need to know if the REST API you are calling supports `GET` or `POST`, or both methods.  The code below is something that works for me, I'm calling my own web service API, so I already know what the API takes and what it will return. It supports both `GET` and `POST` methods, so the less sensitive info goes into the `URL (GET)`, and the info like username and password is submitted as `POST` variables. Also, everything goes over the `HTTPS` connection.

Inside the API code, I encode an array I want to return into json format, then simply use PHP command `echo $my_json_variable` to make that json string availabe to the client.

So as you can see, my API returns json data, but you need to know (or look at the returned data to find out) what format the response from the API is in.

This is how I connect to the API from the client side:

```
$processed = FALSE;
$ERROR_MESSAGE = '';

// ************* Call API:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.myapi.com/api.php?format=json&action=subscribe&email=" . $email_to_subscribe);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// set post data to true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=myname&password=mypass");   // post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// returned json string will look like this: {"code":1,"data":"OK"}
// "code" may contain an error code and "data" may contain error string instead of "OK"
$obj = json_decode($json);

if ($obj->{'code'} == '1')
{
  $processed = TRUE;
}else{
  $ERROR_MESSAGE = $obj->{'data'};
}

...

if (!$processed && $ERROR_MESSAGE != '') {
    echo $ERROR_MESSAGE;
}
```

BTW, I also tried to use `file_get_contents()` method as some of the users here suggested, but that din't work well for me.  I found out the `curl` method to be faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 7):

as @Christoph Winkler mentioned this is a base class for achieving it:

*curl_helper.php*

```
// This class has all the necessary code for making API calls thru curl library

class CurlHelper {

// This method will perform an action/method thru HTTP/API calls
// Parameter description:
// Method= POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data= array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value
public static function perform_http_request($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

}
```

Then you can always include the file and use it e.g.: *any.php*

```
    require_once("curl_helper.php");
    ...
    $action = "GET";
    $url = "api.server.com/model"
    echo "Trying to reach ...";
    echo $url;
    $parameters = array("param" => "value");
    $result = CurlHelper::perform_http_request($action, $url, $parameters);
    echo print_r($result)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `file_get_contents` to issue any http `POST/PUT/DELETE/OPTIONS/HEAD` methods, in addition to the `GET` method as the function name suggests.

[How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: file_get_content is realy bad idea when it comes to API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004805/file-get-contents-or-curl-in-php/24954327 You can set custom method like file_get_contents_curl and use it instead of plain php solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540800/how-to-use-curl-instead-of-file-get-contents

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of clients actually. One of them is [Pest](https://github.com/educoder/pest) - check this out. And keep in mind that these REST calls are simple http request with various methods: GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Symfony there's a great rest client bundle that even includes all of the ~100 exceptions and throws them instead of returning some meaningless error code + message.

You should really check it:
https://github.com/CircleOfNice/CiRestClientBundle

I love the interface:

```
try {
    $restClient = new RestClient();
    $response   = $restClient->get('http://www.someUrl.com');
    $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
    $content    = $response->getContent();
} catch(OperationTimedOutException $e) {
    // do something
}
```

Works for all http methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use third party tools you'd have a look at this one:
https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

This is a completely new way to work with APIs.

First of all you define an entity which is defining the structure of incoming and outcoming data and annotate it with datasources:

```
/*
 * @Entity
 * @DataSource\Select("http://www.myApi.com/products/{id}")
 * @DataSource\Insert("http://www.myApi.com/products")
 * @DataSource\Select("http://www.myApi.com/products/update/{id}")
 * @DataSource\Fetch("http://www.myApi.com/products")
 * @DataSource\Delete("http://www.myApi.com/products/delete/{id}")
 */
class Product {
    private $name;

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Now it's pretty easy to communicate with the REST API:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->setName('test');
// sends an API request POST http://www.myApi.com/products ...
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();

$product->setName('newName');
// sends an API request UPDATE http://www.myApi.com/products/update/1 ...
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Disclaimer: You're the author if this package