# How to interact between php and java webservice

Tags: java, php, webservice-client

I have tried to create Restful Web service using java and netbeans. I have run 'Test RESTful web service' and everything are ok.
But i want to access, the webservice that i have made, using php or codeigniter, how to retrieve content or put content. I have problem with this. I have try like this in my controler.

```
 file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/akunKu/resources/db.akun.akkelompokakun');
```

yes it show content, but where i should put parameter.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the webservice expect GET or POST parameters?

Comment: yes, i have learned from this http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: Watch this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Use the cURL extension.. usually available on all professional web hosts.

Or use NuSphere's NuSoap classes (http://www.nusphere.com/php_script/nusoap.htm)

2nd one is even more easier I believe.