# how to call rest api from view in YII?

Tags: yii

I want to call rest API from view in YII.I know how to call it from simple PHP.

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)

But I dont know how to call it in YII manner.what is the right way to call it in YII?

Answer (score 4):

As **Yii 1.1**

you've not a framework class to do the requests, but you can use **Guzzle** a powerfull PHP HTTP client:

- [docs to REST operations](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json)
- [Github guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

As **Yii 2.0**
you can use **yii2-httpclient**:

- [github yii2-httpclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient)
- [yii2-httpclient documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-request-options.md)

Answer (score -1):

There isn't Yii way to get the data from API so you can use:

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://www.hpgloe.com/json/getrec/?lat=37.234&lon=-122.234');
```

After that you can use [CJSON](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON) helper to decode the data. For example:

```
$response = CJSON::decode($output);
```

Comment: how to call rest with post request , send some data in post request?

Comment: In this case you can use jQuery or CURL (native or CURL wrapper for Yii framework).

Comment: If you want to use jQuery see here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. If you prefer to use the wrapper try http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-curl/ or http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/curl/.