# jQuery autocomplete use asp.net mvc web api 2 data integrate to PHP JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have asp.net mvc web api 2 url. I need to use that web API data integrate to PHP application search and data(postcode display list) auto complete. These below my jQuery and PHP search page code, but it is not working for me. Please tell me why was that?

This is asp.net mvc web api 2 JSON return values.

```
[{"ID":6,"SuburbName":"Carlton North","postcode":"3054","Territory":"MEL-Brunswick","Latitude":-  37.7845911,"Longitude":144.972883,"AuState":"VIC","created":"13/03/2015 12:00:00 AM","updated":"13/03/2015 12:00:00 AM"}
[{"ID":7,"SuburbName":"Carlton South","postcode":"3054","Territory":"MEL-Brunswick","Latitude":-    37.7845911,"Longitude":144.972883,"AuState":"VIC","created":"13/03/2015 12:00:00 AM","updated":"13/03/2015 12:00:00 AM"}
```

This is my jQuery code

```js
var searchRequest = null;
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    maxLength: 5,
    source: function(request, response) {
        if (searchRequest !== null) {
            searchRequest.abort();
        }
        searchRequest = $.ajax({
            url: 'asp.net mvc api web url',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                searchRequest = null;
                response($.map(data.items, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.SuburbName,
                        label: item.SuburbName
                    };
                }));
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            searchRequest = null;
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="search.php">
  Enter your Postcode: 
  <input type="text" name="search" >
  <input name="submit" type="submit" class="auto" value="<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>" /><br />
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $value=$_POST['search'];
}
```

Comment: The "Run code snippet" didn't seem to work. What exception you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any data form that code

Comment: if you inspect the response from the server using either Chrome or Fiddler do you see the data?

Comment: Only I can see data if I use asp.net mvc web api 2 url it'll display data

Comment: When I run PHP code it'll come only JSON 1 (null) 0

Comment: Hello, Please tell me why is not print $value in  here $json = file_get_contents('http://www.wwwcc.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=. $value .'); if I use echo $value somewhere else it display value.

Comment: Rob  you may be on to something. Try either of these two: $json = file_get_contents('wwwcc.com.au/api/api/values?pcode='.$value.'')

or

$json = file_get_contents('wwwcc.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=$value')

Comment: In your above example it seem like you are missing closing single comma

Comment: Thank you for you help, This $json line is working now.

Comment: Hello Mike, $value=$_POST['search'];
$json = file_get_contents('http://wwwcc.com.au/api/api/values?pcode='.$value.''); 
now $value come, but stiil jQuery autocomplete not working. What do I have to do?

Comment: I would try to simplify the autocomplete configuration - try this: 
`$( "#postcode" ).autocomplete({
      source: "asp.net mvc api web url"
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.SuburbName + "<br>" + item.SuburbName + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };`

Comment: Humm ... not sure if it's any simple. But see if that works.

Comment: Hello Mike, I have already hard coded pcode=3023 in my below code. That number has 3 records,  but display now "No search results" where does come from "No search results" ? <input type="text" name="search" class="auto" value="<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>"   >

Comment: $( '.auto' ).autocomplete({ 
source: 'http://www.wwwc.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=3023' 

}
) .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
 return $( "<li>" ) .append( "<a>" + item.SuburbName + "<br>" + item.SuburbName + "</a>" ) .appendTo( ul ); };autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) { return $( "<li>" ) .append( "<a>" + item.SuburbName + "<br>" + item.SuburbName + "</a>" ) .appendTo( ul ); };

Comment: Rob, one other thing ... you may have revised your mark-up but I don't see the element with an id of postalcode `<form method="POST" action="search.php">
Enter your Postcode: 
 <input type="text" name="search" >
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/><br />
</form>`; this element should prob have it `<input type="text" name="search"  id="postalcode">`

Comment: Rob, the "No search result" may be coming back from web api, When you trace the data from web api what you see?

Comment: Hello Mile, I tried both. but not working for me <input type="text" name="search" id="postalcode">
<input type="text" name="search"  class="auto" value="<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>"   >

Comment: web API pcode=3023'; has 3 values. it can't be web API

Comment: I have already update my question below code  <input type="text" name="search"  class="auto" value="<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>"   >

Comment: Can you you please explain to me ""instance" autocomplete( "instance" )

Comment: Hello Mike, I think this case we have to use jQuery Autocomplete before search(Post)?

Comment: I check Fiddler, GET /api/api/values?pcode=3043 HTTP/1.1 no any values return. only valve come post and submit <form method="POST" action="search.php"> What is the solution for auto complete data display before press submit button?

Comment: Hi Rob, i'll try to replicate your test case and see more what may be the issue

Comment: Rob i have created the jsfiddler, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/mike_123/DLLVw/726/

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for your code and your time. please let me know that jQuery library requirement is only these two? <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Hello Mike, I have already copy and past your all code I put my test server but it did not work http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/rob/test.php. Also I added another jquery code and it'll work http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/rob/test1.php, Why was not working test.php page?

Comment: You need to update the url and data properties: $.ajax({
            url: "asp.net mvc api web url",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            type:"POST",

Comment: Also a couple of things to check: 1) the webapi does it live on the same server? if not you need to adjust the settings for cross-domain calls (see here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp); 2) make sure parameter **term** matches the signature of the webapi (postcode???)

Comment: Hello Mike, according to you instruction I did changers but It did not work for me. herewith I am sending you my test URL, you can see source code under view source http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/rob/auto1.php. The page top PHP code included <?php    
$json = file_get_contents('/api/api/values?pcode=3043'); 
$Locations = json_decode($json); 
?> If you want to test use jqery  url: $json, or direct API url.

Comment: Rob, you need to wrap the script into document ready, like this: `$(document).ready(function(){
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    ...
});
`

Comment: also you've left the data: json (there are two of them, comment the first one). See what you get ...

Comment: Hello mike, I have already updated my page http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/rob/auto1.php still same issue. please refer my source code under page view source.

Comment: Hello mike, I have copy your 
http://jsfiddle.net/mike_123/DLLVw/726/ jquery one to one code and paste my test server please use this url 
http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/rob/auto2.php. but it did not work. also please check what I am using library use view source code.

Comment: Helllo mike, this url http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/rob/auto3.php when you check Fiddler Json valve return. but not display in the the page, why was that?

Comment: Hi Rob, i tried to replicate the problem using the web api url in your example, and I'm running into exactly  the same issue where webapi returns data, but autocomplete doesn't pick it up. I tried to use "json**p**", callbacks, etc. - it just wouldn't work. Let me play with it some more and get back to you ...

Comment: Rob, just thought i'd follow up bellow with a properly formatted feedback. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how far you've gone, but one solution would be to wrap http request from the server (PHP) or WebAPI and allow autocomplete to consume local request:

```
        public IEnumerable<Locations> GetLocations(string pcode)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = client.GetAsync("api/values?pcode=" + pcode).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var res = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Locations>>().Result;
            return res;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class Locations
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        public string SuburbName { get; set; }
        public string Territory { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
    }
```

Client side, you've got it correct:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/values",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { pcode: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.SuburbName,
                                label: item.SuburbName
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });          
});
```

Here is a result:

[image]

Comment: Hello Mike, thank for you .net code. but only web API  is .net application. I have to access all data via PHP code. How can I convert your above .net code to PHP ? I try few lines but not wokrs. $client = new HttpClient('http://www.tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/api/values');

Comment: Hello Mike, please refer my PHP code and url http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/tlc/ver4/auto4.php

<?php 
$content=file_get_contents('http://www.tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=3040');
$data=json_decode($content);
?>
foreach($data as $data1{ echo $data1->SuburbName;
}

Comment: hello,  please use this url http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/tlc/ver4/auto7.php and type post code 3073 check your Fiddler it display JSON, TextView,SyntaxView etc.. why did not work Auto complete value display in auto7.php page. What is the mistake??

Comment: Hi Rob, can you check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php to see if you could make webapi request using PHP?

Comment: Rob, when you did all that **$content=file_get_contents('tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=3040'); $data=json_decode($content); ?> foreach($data as $data1{ echo $data1->SuburbName; } **  were you able to get data back?

Comment: For the time being please  use this url naturalbluesapphires.com/tlc/ver4/auto7.php and type post code 3073 check your Fiddler it display JSON, TextView,SyntaxView etc.. why did not work Auto complete value display in auto7.php page. What is the mistake??

Comment: my requirement is use this API http://www.tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=30. Auto complete values will  display on  PHP web application.

Comment: I have added new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201508/web-api-integrate-use-jquery-autocomplete-with-php