# Web API Integrate use jQuery autocomplete with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

Can anyone please tell me how can I do .net MVC web API integrate with PHP web application use jQuery auto complete and display Suburb Name.

I have already added jQuery code to this test url naturalbluesapphires.com/tlc/ver4/auto9.php and when I type post code 3073 if I check in Fiddler it'll display JSON, TextView, SyntaxView etc.. why did not work Auto complete value display in auto9.php page. What is the mistake?

Also how do I display same time suburb name and territory and print valves use PHP echo.

```html
<label for="pcode">Your post code: </label>
<input id="pcode">
```

```js
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $( "#pcode" ).autocomplete({
   delay: 10,
   minLength: 3,
   
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/api/values?",
                    dataType: "json",
     
                    data: { pcode: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.SuburbName,
                                label: item.SuburbName
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
    
        });          
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Well, it seems like you're expecting a JSON (as per your AJAX request) but you're receiving XML from your request URL.

Comment: I am not sure use JSON or AJAX

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6k5xov says you're wanting to get a JSON, but http://prntscr.com/6k5xu5 (where you're requesting) is in the XML format.

Comment: What do I have to change 'dataType: "json"??

Comment: I would change the json to xml, but I'm not sure

Comment: I change to XML (auto10.php) but only return XML data I can see use  Fiddle. not display anything in the website. Are there any way to display data my web use that XML and PHP?

Comment: Are there anyway use this php code <?php    
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.tlcnewsletter.com.au/api/api/values?pcode=3023'); 
$contacts = json_decode($json); 

foreach($contacts as $contact) 
    { 
       
               echo $contact->SuburbName
}

?> and jQuery/Json auto complete and display Suburb Name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620270/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-xml

Comment: if add dataType: 'json', return Json,   dataType: 'xml', return xml. My requirement is data auto complete.

Comment: this mvc web API default return json