# How to enable docker API to access via http

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, docker

I'm trying to manage docker via PHP curl requests. (Using Ubuntu 15.10)

I have followed API documentation but it bit confusing and also followed a few online tutorials but no luck.

This is what I have done so far,
stopped docker daemon and added

```
script
    /usr/bin/docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -d
end script
```

to

```
/etc/init/docker.conf
```

Docker daemon started

This is My PHP script

```
function post_to_url($url, $data, $headers) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //timeout in seconds

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($headers != '') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    if ($data != '') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($return == '') {
        return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    } else {
        return $return;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
//Sample API request
echo post_to_url('http://127.0.0.1:4243/containers/json', '', '');
```

But I did not able to get any output via CURL request?

What I'm missing here?

Comment: In the very last line, `loclhost` should perhaps be `localhost`? :)

Comment: @morphatic  Nope that wasn't the issue. I tried with 127.0.0.1

Comment: in the docker docs I don't see any mention of the `-d` flag that you've added to the script in your `docker.conf` file. Perhaps you meant `-D`. Using the wrong flag could prevent docker from starting properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure that out.

In `/etc/defaults/docker` I put

```
DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock'
```

(Use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` to access API via any host)

My PHP function in the question is not compatible with REST API,

So I have used following function (Source - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802854/1362713))

```
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

And called above function:

```
echo CallAPI('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:4243/images/json', $data = false)
```

and it worked!

Opening up Docker API to the public is a major security risk, so I have used IP address `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`, so my PHP script can still access it.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 15.10 is a system that uses `systemd`. The `/etc/init/docker.conf` file is only used on systems that use upstart.

Read this section in the documentation on how to configure daemon options on a system that uses systemd:

[Custom Docker daemon options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options)

Please note that:

- Port `4243` is no longer the standard port for docker. Use port `2375` (plain) and `2376` (for tls)
- Remember that anybody that's able to obtain access to the API has effectively **root permissions** on your host. So **never** expose an unprotected API

Also note, that there's an (unofficial) PHP client-library that for docker; http://stage1.github.io/docker-php/ that may save you a lot of time and headaches :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. btw I figured that out and posted the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. The existing solutions have not convinced me, so I have written a new Docker API Client in PHP. I also published a docker container to make the API available via HTTP (jarkt/docker-remote-api).
Visit the project page with documentation here: https://github.com/jarkt/docker-php-client

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the docker daemon config and having to restart it, you can use Sherpa to open up a path to the remote API via remote-proxy. Something like:

```
docker run -d \
--name sherpa \
-e CONFIG='[
    { 
        "Path" : "/",
        "Access": "allow",
        "Addresses": ["10.0.0.0/8"]
    }
]' \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
-p 4550:4550 \
djenriquez/sherpa --allow
```

would give you access on port `4550` and only accepts requests from source clients in the `10.0.0.0/8` space. You can customize all kinds of ACLs for the remote API also.

Checkout the introductory post here:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/easily-enable-docker-remote-api-sherpa-dj-enriquez

or directly to the repo here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/djenriquez/sherpa/