# How to integrate the smartsheet in php

Tags: smartsheet-api

How to integrate the smart sheet in my php website.i want to show the smartsheet of each staffs in there dashboard. I want to authenticate and show all smartsheet options in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Smartsheet REST API from PHP to pull back information from Smartsheet and display it in a web page. Please see the [Smartsheet API Documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#overview) for information. Since Smartsheet's API is a standard REST API using OAuth 2, standard PHP libraries for calling REST APIs will work with the Smartsheet API. Some examples of calling REST APIs from PHP are below:

- [Using curl and PHP to talk to a REST service](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/using-curl-and-php-to-talk-to-a-rest-service)
- [Call a REST API in PHP (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php/9802854#9802854)
- [How to make REST calls in PHP](https://support.ladesk.com/index.php?type=page&urlcode=061754&title=How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP&r=1)
- [Make Yahoo! Web Service REST Calls with PHP](https://developer.yahoo.com/php/howto-reqRestPhp.html)
- [Interact with the Force.com REST API from PHP](https://bcws.brightcloud.com/code-samples.php#php)

If you want to experiment with the API without dealing with OAuth, the Smartsheet API supports [User-generated Access Tokens](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#user-generated-access-tokens) to make authentication easier.