# Connectwise REST API Implementation

Tags: rest, api

In my application , I am going to use connectwise API , but I can't figure out how to call their API, like

1. API end point
2. How to pass header
3. How to authentication (I have company id , public and private key)
4. How to make call and take response
5. I am PHP guy

Thanks in advance for any help !!

Answer (score 5):

ConnectWise has a developer portal that is very helpful for this stuff: developer.connectwise.com. If you don't have a login, create a ticket with them to give you access.

Here are basic answers to your questions, though:

1. The endpoint prefix is this: `https://[connectwise_server]/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/` and then you add to the end depending on the resource you're querying
2. I believe the only headers you need are `Content-Type: application/json` and the authentication header (see below)
3. Authentication is BASIC auth. In PHP, that would look something like this.

   ```
   $username = $companyId .'+'. $publicKey;
   $password = $privateKey;
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
   ```
4. A quick search of SO produced this starting point: [Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)
5. I used to be one of those, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information . can you help me that how do I get [connectwise_server] . because I have been provided only company id , public key and private key. Api endpoint is static url except [connectwise_server]. will it be fixed http://api-na.myconnectwise .. like this ?

Comment: If you have a premise installation, [connectwise_server] will be the URL to that server. If you're a cloud client, then the one you reference is correct: api-na.myconnectwise.com. So if you wanted to query the Company API for a Company with id 1, you would submit a GET request to https://api-na.myconnectwise.com/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/company/companies/1

Comment: Actually for the ConnectWise cloud solution the API url is `https://api-na.myconnectwise.net/<version>`. Basically .net vs .com

Comment: Hi All, I'm also have one doubt in Connectwise. Any chance to differentiate our account is in premise or cloud type using host,public and Private key through API.