# Redirect to another url with content

Tags: c#, php

My C# code is calling my API service (PHP), which needs to redirect the request to another url, and process the response before returning it. Here is my C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
WebResponse response = null;
Stream writer = null;

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http://www.somewhere.com/proxy.php);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + this.builder.Boundry;

this.builder.RequestStream.Position = 0;
byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[this.builder.RequestStream.Length];
this.builder.RequestStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);

writer = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
writer.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
writer = null;

response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And then in `proxy.php`:

```
<?php
    // 1. Redirect everything (with the content stream from the C# code) to http://www.elsewhere.com
    // 2. Process the response from http://www.elsewhere.com
    // 3. Return processed data to my C# code
?>
```

How can I do this? It needs to redirect the request stream that I put on this line:

```
writer = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
writer.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: why not just call the elsewhere.com from the start?

Comment: Because `proxy.php` needs to take the response from elsewhere.com and change it before returning it to my C# code.

Comment: @mkaatman `header` won't work in this case because it redirects the request without letting me change the response before sending it back to the caller.

Comment: What do you mean by response? Are you doing more than choosing which URL to redirect to? You aren't trying to send anything else back right?

Comment: elsewhere.com returns a JSON, which I need to change/process (in `proxy.php`) before sending it back to my C# code

Comment: @Darius why not process it directly in your C# code?  Get rid of the middle-man.

Comment: @MrZander Because the processing involves calling other APIs, recording history, etc that the C# app should not know about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use location header in PHP to redirect to another page:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.somesite.com/another_page.php");
  exit();
?>
```

No matter the caller program is C# or other languages.

Comment: This won't work because it won't let me process the response before returning to my C# app.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: `<?php
    header("Location: http://elsewhere");
    echo "never see this line";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) on the PHP side in order to process the result before returning it.

Here is an example of using cURL to get data

```
function getData(){
    $curl = curl_init("http://thewebsite.com/api/whatever");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

This will also depend on your PHP configuration, some installations don't have the cURL module installed/enabled.

Comment: Here is another SO question that has some good cURL examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php

Comment: Will the content that I placed in the request stream (from my C# code) be included in the curl call? Or do I have to manually add that before executing it?

Comment: @Darius You will have to manually add it.  It is an entirely new API call originating from the server running the PHP script.

Comment: Do you know how to add it?

Comment: @Darius Take a look at that link I commented.  `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` should be what you're looking for when attempting to send POST parameters.