# How to hide ajax url link from page sourse

Tags: jquery, ajax

> I want to hide url in ajax from page source,how can i do it.
>   my script(tracking.php)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var from = "";
            $('#loadings').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://apis.andd.ddd/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/<?php echo $number; ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#loadings').hide();
                    console.log(response);
                    document.getElementById('lrid').innerHTML = "LR NO: " + response[0].LRSUFIX + response[0].LR_NO;
                    document.getElementById('consign').innerHTML = response[0].COMPANY_NAME;
                    document.getElementById('from').innerHTML = response[0].LOADFROMMST;
                    document.getElementById('dest').innerHTML = response[0].DESTINATION;
                    document.getElementById('case').innerHTML = response[0].NO_OF_PKT;
                    document.getElementById('lrsta').innerHTML = response[0].LR_STATUS;
                    document.getElementById('lr').innerHTML = response[0].lrLoadStatus;
                    document.getElementById('vecno').innerHTML = response[0].VEHICLE_NO;
                    document.getElementById('lrstatus').innerHTML = response[0].LOADIG_STATUS;
                    document.getElementById('ldate').innerHTML = response[0].DATE;
                }, error: function (errors) {
                    console.log(errors);//alert('hi');                  
                    $('#loadings').hide();
                    $('#error').html("<h2><span style='color:red;'>No data found on this LR No.</span></h2>");                     
                }
            });
        });
    </script
```

> my form(index.html)

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="tracking.php">
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter LR Number" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

> please help me how can i hide url link.

Comment: send the request to PHP.

Comment: Create a php function using switch case and send you call to this page from everywhere with action parameter and then in this function manage calls according action

Answer (score 0):

No, because technically Ajax query is just simple HTTP get/post request.

overall, you shouldn't worry about this. there is no way I'm aware of to hide your ajax calls, but you shouldn't need to.

-you could encrypt the info.

-you could use comet to stream the data on a persistent connection. (super complicated).

-follow good server security practices and not worry about it.

**source**: [here](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/822337-hide-ajax-calls-tools-like-firebug-other)

If you are really worried about this, you could set up kind of an anonymous URL, which will then redirect to where you really want to go based on some variable which is arbitrary.

for example, instead of going to

> *"/Prethors/Users/SearchUsers"*

go to

> *"/AnonymousCall?code=5"*

from which you could execute the code you want for searchusers

Answer (score 0):

Send the request to PHP, then make the call to the API with PHP

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var from = "";
        $('#loadings').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'somephp.php?number='<?php echo $number; ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                .....
            }, error: function (errors) {
                console.log(errors);//alert('hi');                  
                $('#loadings').hide();
                $('#error').html("<h2><span style='color:red;'>No data found on this LR No.</span></h2>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['number']) && is_int($_GET['number'])) {
    $url = 'http://apis.andd.ddd/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/' . $_GET['number'];
    // make your request here
    // send data back to Javascript
}
```

see this post [Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)