# How to bind file_get_contents() return value in text field

Tags: php

I want to print `file_get_contents()` return value in text field.

My form (input.html):

```
<form name="" action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

This is my view page where I want to bind (form.php)

```
<?php 
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
echo $number;
$data = file_get_contents('http://apis.sdsds.sds/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/'.$number);
?>
```

Here is `file_get_contents()` return value:

```
[{"ID":103,"FROM_ID":1,"NAME":"CUTTACK","COMPANY_NAME":"B K TRADING","CMP_ID":8473,"LR_NO":"00107","LR_ID":752,"LMID":17,"TO_ID":4,"DESTINATION":"TALCHER","GODAWN_ID":1,"GODAWN":"BAJARKABATI ROAD","NO_OF_PKT":8.00,"TOPAY_AMOUNT":0.00,"REMARKS":"","LOADIG_STATUS":"Close","LR_STATUS":"Delivered","LOADING_SHEETNO":"00006","MANUAL_LOADSHEET_NO":"","modeof_payment":"PAID","COLLECTED_TOPAY_AMNT":0.00,"LOADFROMMST":"CUTTACK","LOADFROMMSTID":1,"DESTINATION_ID":4,"LOADDESTINATIONNAME":"TALCHER","SUFIX":"BK","MST_GODAWN":1,"GODAWNMASTER":"BAJARKABATI ROAD","LRGODAWN":"BAJARKABATI ROAD","LRSUFIX":"BK","LRGODAWNID":1,"VEHICLE_NO":"OD-05-N-3856","VEHICLEID":799,"basic_freight":320.00,"sur_charge":0.00,"hamali":16.00,"lr_charge":30.00,"service_charge":0.00,"cover_charge":0.00,"dd_charge":0.00,"dp_charge":0.00,"grand_total":366.00,"booking_incharge":"SURYA","clubpoint":0.00,"onloading_charge":0.00,"LOADSHEET_TYPE":"NORMAL","DATE":"2017-04-03T00:00:00","lrConfirmStatus":null,"lrLoadStatus":null}]
```

I want to bind this return value in a text field in bind.php and here is my bind code:

```
<input type="text" name="cmpname" value="<?php echo $data[0].COMPANY_NAME?>"/>
```

But it show warning message, I think some mistake in binding in above text field.

Comment: what warning message?

Comment: it shows a notice

Comment: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant COMPANY_NAME - assumed 'COMPANY_NAME' in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\bind.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />[COMPANY_NAME

Comment: And I remember giving you this suggestion on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084036/how-to-hide-ajax-url-link-from-page-sourse) and you didn't accept my answer

Comment: i mistakenly post that it shows warning but now it show this above notice

Comment: aren't you using AJAX to get the file data?

Comment: echo $data[0]['COMPANY_NAME']

Comment: after using echo $data[0]['COMPANY_NAME'] It shows this warning message  -   <br /><b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'COMPANY_NAME' in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\bind.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to json_decode your text.

```
$data = json_decode($data);
```

You should be able to properly access your value with the following line

```
<input type="text" name="cmpname" value="<?php echo $data[0]->COMPANY_NAME?>"/>
```

Note that i replaced "." with "->"
In php the dot means concatenation.

Comment: Took the words out of my mouth.

Comment: same to you @JaredFarrish :D

Comment: Thank you Dan it working,i am very graceful for your help.

Comment: @dipti please accept this answer as it has solved your problem. +1 Dan Dumitriu

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a json file. With that way you can manipulate it,I have already the json file saved in languages folder.

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['number'])){

$number = $_POST['number'];

$counter=0;
$mydata=0;

$data = file_get_contents('languages/en.json');

$d = json_decode($data);

    foreach ($d as $key) {

        if($counter+1==$number){

            $mydata=$key;
        }

        $counter++;
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JSON example</title>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="cmpname" value="<?php $mydata ?>" placeholder="<?= $mydata ?>">



</body>
</html>
```

as the html form is

```
<form name="formone" action="form.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="number" id="number"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

In your example you move from .html to form.php and you want to put the results to third file(bind.php), you can stay at second .php file