# Use .NET Framework v.4.0 API from PHP

Tags: php, .net, .net-4.0

I have a web application based on symfony2 framework (PHP language) hosted on a LINUX server. I need to use an API from my PHP code. This API is a class library developed using the Microsoft.NET Framework v.4.0.

I cannot modify ou rewrite the API as it is private code. I can only use it from my PHP code.

Thank you for you help,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php might be useful

Comment: Can you be more specific about the .net API ? If the thing you want to call is a .net class library you wont be able to call it from php. Are you trying to execute the assembly on Linux ?

Comment: the API is a Microsoft.NET library that can be used as a standard reference in a .NET project. It is also possible tu use the API library via COM.