# Request an Authorization Code Linkedin

Tags: php, api, curl, linkedin-api, file-get-contents

I learn about linkedin `api` so for start i need to know how i Request an Authorization Code ?

i try so many question with this type here, but i still understand.

From the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#ux) is said to :

"Simple call" :

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile
```

But i need to know how perform that call with `php`.

I try :

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile");
$response = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response);
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php#answer-9802864) but my return is : **NULL**.

**Edit**

My oAuth2.0 end point authorized is `http://localhost`, i dont know if that made problem or are possible.

I put `curl` tag too, becouse the teaching for this purpose is very welcome.

<sub>sorry my english</sub>

Comment: http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/#curl-get

Comment: Tks for atention @TahaPaksu , but with this example retun `404`, maybe some mistake on url request, i check many times the url parameters, souds ok, but not work...

Comment: Negative are welcome, when follow with any tips to be question more better, without that what benefit can it bring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i dont know if that is correct way, but i got with the follow:

To make the request :

```
<?php
header('Location: https:/www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FapiLinkedin%2FDevMagicHat%2Fauth%2Flinkedin/callback&state=xxxxxxxxx');
?>
```

And here is my call back, after request `Linkdin` answer on call back uri.

So in the folder `callback` i create an `index.php` page to receive response:

**localhost/apiLinkedin/DevMagicHat/auth/linkedin/callback/index.php**

```
<?php
$code = $_GET['code'];
$state = $_GET['state'];
echo "Code =>".$code."<br/>"."State =>".$state;
?>
```

i realy dont know if this way is better of others, but work fo me, i hope work fo you too.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to [create an application](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp=) in Linkedin platform and get your client_id

We admit that your redirect url is: http://localhost/index.php, the first thing you should do is to direct the user's browser to LinkedIn's:

**index.php**

```
$params = [
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/index.php', 
    'state' => 'textOfYourChoice'
];

$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?'.http_build_query($params);

header('Location: '.$url);
```

You will get now the linkedin authorization page, just click allow button and you'll direct back to your page index.php with the code passed in the url parameters.

Now in order to get the code value you should check $_GET variable:

**index.php becomes**:

```
if (isset($_GET['code']) {
   die($_GET['code']);
}

$params = [
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/index.php', 
    'state' => 'textOfYourChoice'
];

$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?'.http_build_query($params);

header('Location: '.$url);
```

Comment: i try something like that before using curl, but return `string 0`...]

Comment: @MagicHat, Ok Let me check, I didn't try this before, maybe there is something I forget

Comment: Oh man, no problem, i realy desire, perform that with curl to learn... tks for atention...i wait ;)

Comment: There is no need to use curl here, check my answer again

Comment: Man sorry my honesty, but your answer is the same like my, i say curl, becouse next step for my purpose is `POST` and cant `POST` with `header`function... I apreciate you energy to help, but answer like that is not welcome on SO... realy sry and tks...

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see it