# How can I connect to the REST web services in php?

Tags: php, rest, web-services

How can I connect to the rest web services in php? 
I want to connect to this web service and writing a hotel booking system with php.
hotel web service link
https://pintapin.docs.apiary.io/#reference/users/update-user/update-user
How many ways to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: the answer to this question would be too broad for the stack overflow please refer some documents for this and try some code and then if you get stuck anywhere we are here for help. thank you.

Comment: PHP itself has a REST service?

Comment: I want to connect to this web service and writing a hotel booking system wth php.
https://pintapin.docs.apiary.io/#reference/users/update-user/update-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the curl library will solve what you are trying to do.
Please find the link below for more information on how to call a rest api in PHP.

[call rest api in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)