# how to create & connect magento 2.2 API to iOS app project in Objective C

Tags: php, ios, rest, magento2.2

I want to call Rest APIs provided by magento 2.2. I don't have enough knowledge on how to create REST APIs for magento 2.2 powered website. If I know it then I  could use them for linking to IOS app. Anyone please provide some example or steps to do the same. Or please direct me to the link which provides in depth process of accessing REST APIs in PHP to make it available for a mobile app to access. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access REST APIs in php. Here is a link below to help you out if you have REST API available at your hand.
[Calling REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)

Don't know if there is a way to access REST APIs directly from IOS app.

Answer (score 0):

To create API in Mangento: follow this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785

To make connection between Mangento DB and iOS, you should create API services from Mangento to do these.

Comment: But how to make connection of magento db and iOS through API.Could you please clarify in details OR provide some example or link?

Comment: Are you write API custom from Mangento?

Comment: I want to access already available REST API's given by magento 2.2.