# How to use R1Soft server backup manager API?

Tags: php, api, backup, r1soft, backupmanager

I've done research on R1Soft Server Backup Manager API through this link: 
http://wiki.r1soft.com/display/ServerBackupManager/Use+the+Server+Backup+API
My questions are:
1. How can i do the available actions in the UI with the SBM API? How can i add a protected machine to SBM, for example, through the API? 
2. How to use the php scripts mentioned in /apisamples?
3. How to use the classes mentioned in the url /apidoc?
I'll be really grateful if someone could help with these issues.

Comment: Use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make the requests to the API. Your link gives a 404 btw..

Comment: Your question is actually pretty broad. I suggest giving this link a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php try it out yourself and then come back to stackoverflow once you have a more detailed singular issue with example code on why it doesn't work for you.