# How to get Outlook calendar events to sync with PHP calendar

Tags: php, outlook-restapi

How do I get Outlook events calendar and sync with PHP calendar?

I have tried this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events");
req.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
req.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
req.onload = function (e) {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
        // Check if the get was successful
        if (req.status === 201) {
            console.log(req.response);
        }
    }
};
req.onerror = function (e) {
    // Catching errors
};
req.send(jsonData);
```

Any idea about the PHP example?

Comment: This looks like javascript. what have you tried in PHP?

Comment: no idea about php code, if you have idea about it, please suggest it.

Comment: i have loads of idea, but why are you showing javascript code in a PHP question? have you tried to search SO for "call rest service from PHP"? a quick search brings up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php I am just trying to figure out what you are actually asking.

Comment: My question is i want to sync outlook calendar  events to my PHP calendar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want get Outlook calendar events to sync with PHP calendar, you need to specify the `Prefer: odata.track-changes` header in all sync requests except those that include a skipToken that is returned from a previous sync request.

For more information, you could refer to the below link:

[Sync events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#sync-events)