# How to get and display an image from a guzzle request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to display an image from a guzzle request, everything worked fine but I am failing to display the image.

This is the result I get, when trying to get users' data

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#427 (6) { ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> string(2) "OK" ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> int(200) ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> array(14) { ["Server"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Cowboy" } ["Connection"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "keep-alive" } ["X-Powered-By"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Express" } ["X-Timestamp"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "1556374181931" } ["Content-Disposition"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(51) "attachment; filename =profile_img-1556366764744.jpg" } ["X-Sent"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } ["Accept-Ranges"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "bytes" } ["Cache-Control"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "public, max-age=0" } ["Last-Modified"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Sat, 27 Apr 2019 12:06:07 GMT" } ["Etag"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "W/"12d37-16a5eb034ec"" } ["Content-Type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["Content-Length"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "77111" } ["Date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Sat, 27 Apr 2019 14:09:41 GMT" } ["Via"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "1.1 vegur" } } ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> array(14) { ["server"]=> string(6) "Server" ["connection"]=> string(10) "Connection" ["x-powered-by"]=> string(12) "X-Powered-By" ["x-timestamp"]=> string(11) "X-Timestamp" ["content-disposition"]=> string(19) "Content-Disposition" ["x-sent"]=> string(6) "X-Sent" ["accept-ranges"]=> string(13) "Accept-Ranges" ["cache-control"]=> string(13) "Cache-Control" ["last-modified"]=> string(13) "Last-Modified" ["etag"]=> string(4) "Etag" ["content-type"]=> string(12) "Content-Type" ["content-length"]=> string(14) "Content-Length" ["date"]=> string(4) "Date" ["via"]=> string(3) "Via" } ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> string(3) "1.1" ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#425 (7) { ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> resource(350) of type (stream) ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> NULL ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> string(10) "php://temp" ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> array(0) { } } }
```

```
public function getUserProfileImg(Request $request){

    $userid = $_COOKIE['id'];

    $requestResult = $this->sendGetWithHeader('users/image/'.$userid );

    //$result = $requestResult->getBody()->readfile($filename);

    //$result = $requestResult->getBody();
    //$body = json_decode((string) $requestResult->file($pathToFile, $headers), true);

    //$status = $requestResult->getStatusCode();
    var_dump($requestResult);

    //var_dump($result);
}
```

I am expecting an image

Answer (score 9):

Once you obtain the response for the image from guzzle,

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://www.example.com']);
$response = $client->request('GET', 'wallpaper/wallpaper-preview.jpg', ['stream' => true]);
```

then you can encode it as base64 and send it with a format. You can use [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function provided by php.

> `'data:image/jpeg;base64,your-base-64-encodedstring'`
> **example :** `'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAAEwAMQAAJ2M5Me98GRK1DoYyYBr3PHv++Pe99XO81Y50auc6PBkZEgpzbmt7HJa2I57fS3CqU7XGYgE+GqHvrLJ8Tr6qXmqiwAF9CffgnMNqmWHAWNBwwGsKpKsrmJqltOOV69nuYxSkqpoTata18rWtrr1rTIIAQA7'`

```
$body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$base64 = base64_encode($body);
$mime = "image/jpeg";
$img = ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
return "<img src=$img alt='ok'>";
```

## Extra

you can obtain mime type($mime in above code snippet) from response using, `$response->getHeader('Content-Type')[0];`

Answer (score 0):

The following code sample to retrieve/display an image from [kodementor.com](https://www.kodementor.com/using-guzzle-with-laravel-example/)
The key is to `echo` the results so that the image is displayed.

```
public function promiseGuzzleRequest()
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org/']); //your domain

    // Initiate each request but do not block
    $promises = [
        'image' => $client->getAsync('/image'),
        'png'   => $client->getAsync('/image/png'),
        'jpeg'  => $client->getAsync('/image/jpeg'),
        'webp'  => $client->getAsync('/image/webp')
    ];

    // Wait on all of the requests to complete. Throws a ConnectException
    // if any of the requests fail
    $results = Promise\unwrap($promises);

    // Wait for the requests to complete, even if some of them fail
    $results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();

    // You can access each result using the key provided to the unwrap
    // function.
    echo $results['image']['value']->getHeader('Content-Length')[0];
    echo $results['png']['value']->getHeader('Content-Length')[0];

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rachel Gallen but my goal is to use stream to get an image from a guzzle request. I will appreciate it if you can help

Comment: This is my code below 

try { $result = $this->gClient->request('GET', $url, [ 'headers' => [ 'Authorization'=>'Bearer '.$this->accessToken ], [ 'stream' => true, ] ]); } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) { $this->getGetErr = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()); return $this->getGetErr; } //\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException check return $result;