# Laravel fetch image from external API, then visually crop, resize, and save

Tags: laravel, crop, jcrop, cropperjs, croppie

I'm sorry in advance for such a general question, but I'm having a hard time getting it answered by google alone. Perhaps I'm not asking the right question?

Here's what I need to do:

- Need to fetch an image from an external API.
- Visually crop and resize the image.
- Save transformed image to DB.

I was looking at some js libraries such as jcrop, Croppie, and cropperjs, but all of those
only let me manually upload the images. I'm wondering if there is a solution for this already? Or perhaps someone has done this before and is willing to share their solution?

I'm doing this in Laravel btw, and all of this will be performed in the backend only.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use [image intervention](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

Comment: Image intervention doesn't have a visual editor -- it can only apply the transformations programmatically, so it's not gonna work for me unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: you want to download the image from backend then show it to the frontend and the crop it and save it again, is that right?

Comment: you can use guzzle to download the image, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077922/9471283) as reference, then use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uqy0m1Lc/23/) example if you want to use vanilla js, or if you want to use jquery and cropper.js then use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/psbolden/1hdq04dj/2/) example.

Comment: @bhucho Yes, that's correct. To better illustrate my use case: Instead of uploading the image manually, I want to input a url, get the desired image back as a response from an API, apply the cropping/resizing visually, and then save. The reason I mentioned  the backend at all is because it will be done by me only. There's no front for random users to mess around with.

Comment: I have provided reference above, don't forget to upvote the persons answer which helped, if it does not help you can inform in here to stackoverflow community

Comment: @bhucho Thank you! I'm working through your linked examples and hopefully something will come out of it. Will post an update later on.

Answer (score 0):

For downloading an image from url you can use curl directly:

```
    function downloadImage($url, $saveto)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $raw = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (file_exists($saveto)) {
            unlink($saveto);
        }
        $fp = fopen($saveto, 'x');
        fwrite($fp, $raw);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Or you can use a package like Intervention:

```
    function downloadImage($url, $saveto)
    {
        $path = '/your_storage/';

        $filename = basename($url);

        $image = Image::make($url);
        //for resize and crop you can use resize and crop methods like below
        //$image =  $image->resize(128, 72);  example for resize
        $image->save(public_path($path . $filename));
    }
```