# File Download via API using Guzzle

Tags: php, iis, guzzle

I'm still on the learning slopes with Guzzle, but am stumped with this issue...

I'm trying to retrieve an audio file from a 3rd party API using Guzzle.  I've written a class with a number of functions and they all work apart from the very last stage of the 'download' function - the browser does not prompt to save the audio file

Call to get audio file, using AJAX

```
$callRows.on("click", ".download", function() {

    const $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().hide().next().show();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "submgmt",
        data : {
            task   : "getMedia",
            target : $this.data("id")
        },
        success  : function(data) {

            $this.parent().show().next().hide();

        },
        error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $dialog.attr("title", textStatus);
            $dialog.html("<br>" + errorThrown + "<br><br><h4>Click OK to continue</h4>");
            $dialog.dialog({
                buttons  : {
                    "OK" : function () {
                        $dialog.dialog("destroy");
                    }
                },
                dialogClass : "no-close",
                modal       : true,
                resizable   : false
            });
            $this.parent().show().next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**FIRST TRY**
Function to call download function

```
$ucCall = new ucCalls($ucAuth);

try {

    $response = $ucCall->getMedia($target);

    if ($response['code']===404) {
        $result['ERROR'] = "1";
        $result['DETAILS'] = "File is no longer available";
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Date: " . $response['headers']['Date'][0]);
        header("Cache-Control: " . $response['headers']['Cache-Control'][0]);
        header("Pragma: " . $response['headers']['Pragma'][0]);
        header("Expires: " . $response['headers']['Expires'][0]);
        header("Content-Type: " . $response['headers']['Content-Type'][0]);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($response['filename']) . '"');
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($response['filename']));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($response['filename']);
        exit;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result['ERROR']   = "1";
    $result['DETAILS'] = $e->getCode() . " - " . $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
```

Class to retrieve audio files from 3rd party API

```
class ucCalls {

private Client $client;

public function __construct($authString)
{
    $this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://url-of-host',
        'timeout'  => 5,
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $authString,
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the unencrypted MP3 media for a (completed) recording
 * @param string $id
 * @return array
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getMedia(string $id): array
{

    try {

        $temp_file = sys_get_temp_dir() . "\uc" . make_id(6) . ".mp3";
        $resource = Utils::tryFopen($temp_file, 'w');

        $response = $this->client->request('GET','fw/path/to/audio/file/store/' . $id . '/Media', ['sink' => $resource]);

        return [
            'code'     => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'headers'  => $response->getHeaders(),
            'filename' => $temp_file
        ];

    } catch (ConnectException $e) {
        error_log(print_r("## EXCEPTION ## ucCalls (getMedia) - ConnectException -> " . $e->getMessage(),true));
        throw new Exception ("Connection Error",500);
    } catch (ServerException|ClientException $e) {
        error_log(print_r("## EXCEPTION ## ucCalls (getMedia) - ServerException|ClientException -> " . $e->getMessage(),true));
        throw new Exception ($e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase(),$e->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
        error_log(print_r("## EXCEPTION ## ucCalls (getMedia) - GuzzleException -> " . $e->getMessage(),true));
        throw new Exception ("Unhandled Exception",400);
    }

}
```

}

**SECOND TRY** was to try using the Guzzle Stream

Function to call download function

```
$ucCall = new ucCalls($ucAuth);

try {
    
    $ucCall->getMedia($target);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result['ERROR']   = "1";
    $result['DETAILS'] = $e->getCode() . " - " . $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
```

Class

```
public function getMedia(string $id)
{

    try {

        $temp_file = sys_get_temp_dir() . "\uc" . make_id(6) . ".mp3";
        $resource = Utils::tryFopen($temp_file, 'w+');
        $stream = Utils::streamFor($resource);

        $this->client->request('GET','fw/path/to/audio/file/store/' . $id . '/Media', ['sink' => $stream]);

        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($stream->getMetadata('uri')) . '"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($stream->getMetadata('uri')));

        echo $stream;

    } catch (ConnectException $e) {
        error_log(print_r("## EXCEPTION ## ucCalls (getMedia) - ConnectException -> " . $e->getMessage(),true));
        throw new Exception ("Connection Error",500);
    } catch (ServerException|ClientException $e) {
        error_log(print_r("## EXCEPTION ## ucCalls (getMedia) - ServerException|ClientException -> " . $e->getMessage(),true));
        throw new Exception ($e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase(),$e->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
        error_log(print_r("## EXCEPTION ## ucCalls (getMedia) - GuzzleException -> " . $e->getMessage(),true));
        throw new Exception ("Unhandled Exception",400);
    }
}
```

Both these functions create the audio file in a temp store on my local web server, so the audio file retrieval from the 3rd party works.  This is where I get stumped...

The file appears to transfer to the client, the header attributes are recognised and the correct amount of data is transfer (filesize) - but the client browser (tested in Edge and Firefox) is not prompting to save the file.  Just getting an encoded string, as per the screenshots...

[image: file created on local server]

[image: headers on response from attempt 1]

[image: headers on response from attempt 2]

[image: server response from both requests identical]

Any thoughts or guidance would be appreciated...

Comment: when you show the media to browser use proper headers such as `Content-type: application/octet-stream` and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=audio.mp3` by default it sends as text/html

Comment: Thanks @bhucho, tried that and tried several content-types, including `audio/mpeg`, `audio/mp3`, `application/octet-stream` - all give the same response...

Comment: then there is a way though you should have gotten the audio file(I will try it later), try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077922/9471283) answer just for audio change format by audio/mpeg and pass it in audio tag, you can also check your audio encode from here https://base64.guru/converter/encode/audio

Comment: there is a method to do similar thing in js as well

Comment: @bhucho, that's actually a great help thanks...  I can see the data payload from the webserver to the client browser is already base64 encoded...  so I'm going to add a media player to the page to allow the user to listen to the audio file.  The 'download' option can then just be an FTP to a Shared Folder on a domain file server.  That'll work out better as it will mean we dont have to worry about the audio file on client computers...

Comment: I have written an answer, will help others, if it worked for you, you can accept the answer, also I will suggest if possible to upvote the answer that was used as help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the encoded response you can check it whether it is base64 encoded or not or use `base64_encode($content)` provided by php.

```
$encoded_response = 'your encoded string';
$base64 = base64_encode($encoded_response);
$mime = "audio/mpeg";
$img = ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64); // would be like data:audio/mpeg;base64,YxAAEaAIEeUAQAgBgNg...
<audio autoplay controls src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,YxAAEaAIEeUAQAgBgNg...">
  The “audio” tag is not supported by your browser.
</audio>
```