# How to parse JSON and access results

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using CURL to send a request. The response dataType is `json`. How can I parse this data and insert it into the database?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/SimpleSMSsendWithPostback?        PhoneNumber=18887477474&Message=test&LicenseKey=LICENSEKEY';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

curl_close($cURL);



print_r($result);

?>
```

JSON Output:

```
{
    "Cancelled": false,
    "MessageID": "402f481b-c420-481f-b129-7b2d8ce7cf0a",
    "Queued": false,
    "SMSError": 2,
    "SMSIncomingMessages": null,
    "Sent": false,
    "SentDateTime": "/Date(-62135578800000-0500)/"
}
```

Comment: Try [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I would recommend removing your licence key from your original post? People might be able to use this to send SMS from the service you are using.

Comment: rotate the keys. As anyhow, in the edited sequence, the license key is visible.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If your `$result` variable is a string json like, you must use `json_decode` function to parse it as an **object** or **array**:

```
$result = '{"Cancelled":false,"MessageID":"402f481b-c420-481f-b129-7b2d8ce7cf0a","Queued":false,"SMSError":2,"SMSIncomingMessages":null,"Sent":false,"SentDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"}';
$json = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json);
```

### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [Cancelled] => 
    [MessageID] => 402f481b-c420-481f-b129-7b2d8ce7cf0a
    [Queued] => 
    [SMSError] => 2
    [SMSIncomingMessages] => 
    [Sent] => 
    [SentDateTime] => /Date(-62135578800000-0500)/
)
```

Now you can work with `$json` variable as an array:

```
echo $json['MessageID'];
echo $json['SMSError'];
// other stuff
```

---

References:

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - PHP Manual

Answer (score 12):

The main problem with your example code is that the `$result` variable you use to store the output of `curl_exec()` does not contain the body of the HTTP response - it contains the value `true`. If you try to `print_r()` that, it will just say "1".

The [`curl_exec()` reference](https://www.php.net/curl_exec) explains:

> ## Return Values
>
> Returns **`TRUE`** on success or **`FALSE`** on failure. However, if the **`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`** option is set, it will return the result on success, **`FALSE`** on failure.

So if you want to get the HTTP response body in your `$result` variable, you must first run

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

After that, you can call `json_decode()` on `$result`, as other answers have noted.

On a general note - the curl library for PHP is useful and has a lot of features to handle the minutia of HTTP protocol (and others), but if all you want is to `GET` some resource or even `POST` to some URL, and read the response - then [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) is all you'll ever need: it is much simpler to use and have much less surprising behavior to worry about.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
$result = curl_exec($cURL);
$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

Now you can access `MessageID` from `$result['MessageID']`.

As for the database, it's simply using a query like so:

```
INSERT INTO `tableName`(`Cancelled`,`Queued`,`SMSError`,`SMSIncommingMessage`,`Sent`,`SentDateTime`) VALUES('?','?','?','?','?');
```

Prepared.