# JSON decode, Parse JSON response and Undefined Index

Tags: php, json

Trying to use some decoded json data, but I'm unable to extract it to use.  I've looked at other examples that should work, but haven't worked for me.

What am I missing?

(I'm trying to do what is in the first answer of [How to parse json response from CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016506/how-to-parse-json-response-from-curl) )

**Raw JSON**

```
{"CustomerOriginId":123456}
```

**JSON Decode:**

```
$result = json_decode($head, true);
```

**Print_R results (print_r($result);):**

```
Array ( [CustomerOriginId] => 123456 )
```

**Var_Dump results (var_dump($result);):**

```
array(1) { ["CustomerOriginId"]=> int(123456) }
```

My attempts to extract the data for use:

**Attempt 1**

***Attempt 1 Code:***

```
$test45 = $result["CustomerOriginID"];
echo $test45;
```

***Attempt 1 Error:***

```
Notice: Undefined index: CustomerOriginID
```

**Attempt 2**

***Attempt 2 Code:***

```
$test46 = $result['CustomerOriginID'];
echo $test46;
```

***Attempt 2 Result:***

```
Notice: Undefined index: CustomerOriginID
```

**Attempt 3**

***Attempt 3 Code:***

```
$test47 = $result[0]['CustomerOriginID'];
echo $test47;
```

***Attempt 3 Result:***

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

**Attempt 4**

***Attempt 4 Code:***

```
$test48 = $result[1]['CustomerOriginID'];
echo $test48;
```

***Attempt 4 Result:***

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
```

I'm sure it's something small, but I haven't found an answer as of yet.

Cheers!

Comment: That's interesting that `ABCDEF` gets parsed as an `int`. Is this *exactly* what you've been working with?? The *actual* outputs? What does your JSON look like?

Comment: try... doing index 0 and 1 as strings.

Comment: Show us the real json

Comment: sorry about that, updated with the real json info.

Comment: "ID" is not the same as "Id"!

Comment: Thanks to all for noting the difference between ID and Id, that was the missing piece... needed a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index for your array is "CustomerOriginId", not "CustomerOriginID" (note the case).

```
$json  = '{"CustomerOriginId":123456}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

print $array['CustomerOriginId'];  // outputs 123456
```

Answer (score 1):

**Undefined Index** usually means you are accessing the array value the wrong way.
The index must match `CustomerOriginId` or it will be undefined.

Try this:

```
$json='{ "CustomerOriginId" : 123456 }';
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$CustomerOriginId = $result['CustomerOriginId'];
echo 'CustomerOriginId = '.$CustomerOriginId;
```

or without associative array

```
$json='{ "CustomerOriginId" : 123456 }';
$result = json_decode($json);
$CustomerOriginId = $result->CustomerOriginId;
echo 'CustomerOriginId = '.$CustomerOriginId;
```

Comment: Please add an *explanation* instead of just posting code which is extremely similar to what the OP already has.

Comment: sorry , I added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
$x = json_decode('{"CustomerOriginId":123456}', true);
print_r($x); 
print $x['CustomerOriginId'];
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [CustomerOriginId] => 123456
)
123456
```