# how to query json with numeric variables?

Tags: php, json

I can't bring out the genre (action and science fiction).
I am using this `$title = $array->movie->title;`  for the title and more, but with genre it's not working. Idea please ?

```
<!-- language-all: lang-json -->



stdClass Object
    (
        [movie] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 27405
                [movieType] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [code] => 4002
                        [$] => Long-métrage
                    )

                [originalTitle] => Oblivion
                [title] => Oblivion
                [keywords] => Horizons Oblivion Oblivion 
                [productionYear] => 2013
                [nationality] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [code] => 5002
                                [$] => U.S.A.
                            )

                    )

                [genre] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [code] => 13025
                                [$] => Action
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [code] => 13021
                                [$] => Science fiction
                            )

                    )
```

Comment: Why is `$` an object property name though?

Comment: $genre = $array->movie->genre->[0]->[$];   not working i'm bloqued mate :/

Comment: genre is an array so it should be `$array->movie->genre[0]->code`

Comment: @Boom Ok, variable name should not be `$array` if what you have inside is a stdclass object. So, it will be `$array->movie->genre[0]->{'$'}`. IMO, you really need to fix property names and make it more readable.

Comment: There is solution and it's working :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805011/decode-json-with-number-object-in-php
Thanks you all
Ps : $array = json_decode($result, TRUE);  (associative) array ...

Comment: [echo implode(', ', array_column($object->movie->genre, '$'));](https://3v4l.org/KIG3H)