# How to save a JSON response to $_SESSION

Tags: php, json

I'm authenticating a user using the Linkedin API and everything is fine up until I make the call to get the access token. E.g:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?
grant_type=authorization_code&code=12345
&redirect_uri=https://myredirect.com/callback.php&client_id=123456789
&client_secret=12345
```

Usually these types of calls return the access_token in the URL so I can either use $_GET or $_POST, but this returns a basic page with the JSON response:

```
{"access_token":"ABCDEFG","expires_in":5183078}
```

How can I take that access_token and put it into a $_SESSION variable? Can I split the response and then use AJAX somehow?

Comment: php code will be required for better help ?

Comment: btw, use curl or file_get_contents to get the JSON response in string then use `json_decode`. something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016506/how-to-parse-json-response-from-curl

Comment: Thanks Jigar! Exactly what I used to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Take the $json_var and use json_decode($json_var, true);
That will turn the $json_var into an associative array

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to even get it into a variable, it's displayed automatically after using the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['f1']="Hai this is test";//This seesion will be lost
$json='{"access_token":"ABCDEFG","expires_in":5183078}';
$_SESSION=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

When we use $_SESSION as left side variable all the keys which are previously stored values are ignored.So be careful with that.

Comment: `$_SESSION=json_decode($json,true);` is a VERY BAD IDEA ! you are overwriting the whole global session variable.