# How to encode plain text response to JSON and take specific Data using PHP CURL

Tags: php, json, api, curl, encode

I am getting api response in plain text format. So operation with response data I need to encode the response into JSON format. Then I can easily grab the desire response data and use it.

Request CODE(Sample) ::

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.arshohag.me/test",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>      "login=testapp&key=152456&md5=chasdg4as432&action=test",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo $response;

        }
```

Response CODE(Sample) ::

```
id=2566546
authentication_key=74448975
error_code=0
error_txt=Test Ok
```

I want to encode The response is in JSON format like this -

```
{
  "id" : "2566546",
  "authentication_key" : "74448975",
  "error_code" : "0",
  "error_txt" : "Test Ok"
}
```

and also grab the data like this -

```
 $id=array["id"];
 echo $id;
```

Comment: uhm ... [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) ?

Comment: Structure the data, then json_encode it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rawText = "
id=2566546
authentication_key=74448975
error_code=0
error_txt=Test Ok
";

// Split by new line
// array_filter to skip empty values
$linesArray = array_filter(preg_split('/\R/', $rawText));

$craftedArray = array();
foreach($linesArray as $line) {
  $tempArray = explode("=", $line);
  $craftedArray[$tempArray[0]] = $tempArray[1];
}

// Encode to JSON Object
echo json_encode($craftedArray);
```

Output:

```
{
id: "2566546",
authentication_key: "74448975",
error_code: "0",
error_txt: "Test Ok"
}
```

To get data back from JSON:

```
// Decode JSON. Assume JSON object is stored in $jsonData
$decodedData = json_decode($jsonData);
var_dump($decodedData);

// Access like below
$id = $decodedData->id;
echo "\nID is: ".$id;
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(7) "2566546"
  ["authentication_key"]=>
  string(8) "74448975"
  ["error_code"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["error_txt"]=>
  string(7) "Test Ok"
}

ID is: 2566546
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it by json_encode. Use it like this

var_dump(json_decode($response, true));

Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: json_encode doesn't work out here cause it's a plain txt

Comment: need some encoding algorithm

Comment: Please check this, I hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016506/how-to-parse-json-response-from-curl

Answer (score -2):

This method works for Java, you can convert it to your language if each line ends with \r\n

```
String jsonStringConverter(String stringResponse) {
String[] parts = stringResponse.split("\\r\\n");
String jsonString = "{\"";
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    jsonString += parts[i].replace("=", "\":\"");
    jsonString += (i < parts.length - 1) ? "\", \"" : "";
}
return jsonString += "\"}";
```

}

Comment: $lines = explode("\n", $response);
   $output = Array();
   $thisElement = & $output;
   foreach($lines as $line) {
     $elements = explode(":", $line);
     if (count($elements) > 1) {
    $thisElement[trim($elements[0])] = $elements[1];
     }
     if(strstr($line, "{")) {
      $elements = explode("{", $line);
      $key = trim($elements[0]);
      $output[$key] = Array();
      $thisElement = & $output[$key];
     }
     if(strstr($line, "}")) {
      $thisElement = & $output;
     }
   }
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($output);
   echo '</pre>';

Comment: I am using this to convert the txt into plain text .. but I get "t" or "tt" in the output