# PHP - Read Json and parse to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to read the returned json below but i keep getting errors.

**Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

I'm fetching the json via curl and then **json_decode**($data);

```
foreach($array as $a)
{
   switch($a)
   {
       case"BTC":
         //do something
       case"ETH":
         //do something


   }

}
```

Url :

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,LTC,XMR,XRP,DASH,ZEC&tsyms=USD

Var Dump Results :

```
object(stdClass)#405 (6) { ["BTC"]=> object(stdClass)#404 (1) { ["USD"]=> float(13571.4) } ["LTC"]=> object(stdClass)#406 (1) { ["USD"]=> float(235.57) } ["XMR"]=> object(stdClass)#407 (1) { ["USD"]=> float(399.11) } ["XRP"]=> object(stdClass)#408 (1) { ["USD"]=> float(1.83) } ["DASH"]=> object(stdClass)#409 (1) { ["USD"]=> float(1000.25) } ["ZEC"]=> object(stdClass)#410 (1) { ["USD"]=> float(658.29) } }
```

Comment: @nerdyDev please avoid providing solutions as comments.  Better still, vote to close this page as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json response from CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016506/how-to-parse-json-response-from-curl)

Comment: ok will remove my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Decode as Associative Array

For decoding JSON as an array, you have to pass **assoc** parameter to the `json_decode` function.

When the **assoc** parameter is TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Refer [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information regarding the function.

**Example Code**

```
json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: If this is the solution, then this question is an under-researched, super-mega-duplicate on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a second parameter to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which allows you to parse json data as associative arrays.
try:

```
json_decode($data, true);
```