# Can I develop separate API Calls with php for mobile app using wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

i have the latest installation of wordpress. what i want to do is this:

Suppose i have a site at www.mysite.com and it is running wordpress now i want to create API for mobile app to get data from site using php.

can i create separate API for to get data from wordpress site?

if it can, How to create?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a wordpress plugin for creating an API from your site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751973/is-there-a-wordpress-plugin-for-creating-an-api-from-your-site)

Comment: Ok  thanks mate @fzxt

Answer (score 2):

You can try WP REST API. Install this plugin to your wordpress site then, you can access your site data through api calls.

Comment: I am asking how to create api calls for website? @ved

Comment: You can access data through APIs. Try it.

Comment: Are you developed before like this?@ved

Answer (score 1):

Install JSON API plugin for web services here is the link https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

you can also make extra web service and change webservice by modifying plugin files.

Comment: using that JSON API plugin will get automatic api call for all plugins?

Comment: No, it will give basic web services for your wordpress posts , pages , categories etc. if you like my answer then upvote it.

Comment: Follow this Link https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/ it will help  you for how to call json web service using this plugin

Answer (score 1):

**Try - WP REST API V2**

http://v2.wp-api.org/

downlaod plugin and install it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

just type `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` in end of your site url and you will get all post.

for get all post

```
www.mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

For the search functionality - search test post

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[s]=test
```

much more details from this link http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Note for best result use latest version of WP

other is you can also try Json api plugin but this 1 is best.

Comment: my site is http://activealfie.co.uk/ in this search button is there for that i have to write api call for mobile app

Comment: after activated this plugin website showing blank page

Comment: which one i have to select ?

Comment: Version 2 not supported to mysite so installed version 1 but i am getting like this [{"code":"json_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"}]

Comment: i will suggest then you can also try this 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

or you can also make your custom core php api too.