# WordPress REST API Version 2

Tags: wordpress

[image]I am using Wordpress version 4.4.1. And i am trying to activate WP REST API Version 2 plugin. And it activated successfully. But When i go to wp-json link it show the **error 404 "URL not found"**. Anyone have any idea why i am getting this error. Thanks in advance

Following is my link try to get a wp-json:-

> [localhost/restDemo/wp-json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lazQ1.png)
>   [image]

Comment: I think the V2 is on this structure ```http://localhost/restDemo/wp-json/wp/v2/``` e.g. ```http://localhost/restDemo/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[posts_per_page]=4&filter[orderby]=ehem```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34893592/3639939

Comment: Find the first screen shot. Still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Base on your screenshot, try
`localhost/restDemo/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`